# Is it common for the academic hiring process to be rigged?

Tags: job-search

Here's what one faculty member told me about how hiring works at their department.

There are maybe 10-12 people on the hiring committee and they rate applicants on a scale. There are a bunch of different fields, but two different fields are sometimes lumped together, say field A consists of fields A1 and A2. What happens is that the faculty in field A1 will rate anyone in field A2 with the lowest possible rating, in effect rigging the system so that only faculty who work in field A1 actually get hired. And in fact, when you look at who gets hired in the department, it's *always* people who work in field A1, never A2.

How common is this?

Comment: What country is this? How is the committee selected?

Comment: R1 university in the U.S. Not sure how the committee is selected.

Comment: Surely it's legitimate for the department to decide, collectively, to prefer to hire in field A1 instead of A2.  If they reach that decision through broken internal politics, well, that's their problem.

Comment: I imagine it's nontrivial if the job posting is for a position in A1 (vs an open field request).

Comment: @NateEldredge It's one thing if the A1 group uses department politics to ensure that the position description and advertisement are written to promote a hire in their subfield.  It's a different issue if the A1 group plays this game in ways that aren't consistent with the advertisement.  A dean might well have something to say about this if (for example) the advertisement was written to favor applicants in area A2 and the A1 members of the committee ignored the advertisement.

Comment: Also, it's quite possible that a dean will decide the department has enough A1's and tell it to hire an A2.

Comment: not sure how a committee member preferring someone in their field means the process is rigged: there are so many variables that go in a ranking.  One of them of course is that one or more committee member might just be idiots, but again this does not make the process rigged.

Comment: Where I live there are hiring committees (examination juries) made up by 4 or 5 people. Personal acquaintance, clientelism, and favoritism run rampant. It's normal for a person researching area A to end up teaching area C (and in a few years get tenure), even without any research, teaching, or study experience, because he needs a job and because he graduated under supervision of some of the faculty. And no one with experience in field C would even apply because it would be an entry-level salary, always. That's what I call rigged.

Comment: We really should stop thinking that there is such a thing as "objective merit" which can be totally ordered, along with the corollary assumption that if X has more "objective merit" than Y, then it perpetrates an injustice if Y gets something that X doesn't. This is a juvenile and ludicrously simplistic way to conceptualize fairness.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning: I was just thinking about this. I think the only way there could be a "true meritocracy" is if everyone was born with the same gender, had the same family upbringing, had the same family income, went to the same schools, etc. It's impossible to control for all of these things.

Answer (score 6):

It’s common for academic hiring to arouse strong feelings and opinions, and for faculty members to express those opinions in a variety of ways, and to exert their influence within the department, also in a variety of ways, in order to achieve an outcome they view as preferable.

Some of the ways in which people exert their influence may strike certain other people — especially people who were hoping for a different outcome — as aggressive or distasteful. Does that mean the process is “rigged”? I don’t think so; not necessarily, anyhow. If you are a member of a search committee and think it would be better for your department to hire someone working in field A1 than A2, it seems only natural that you will vote and rank candidates accordingly. If this leads your department to always hire in A1 and never A2, that simply reflects the balance of opinions of the department’s faculty. This is how institutions run themselves. For all we know, preferring A1 to A2 may actually be a sensible thing in this situation and in the best interests of the department. Even if it isn’t, it’s valid to have that as a preference, and it seems valid (if perhaps less than maximally collegial) to express that preference in the way you described when you are a search committee member, unless the practice is somehow violating some rule or policy.

Comment: Everyone in A1 agrees to give everyone in A2 the lowest possible rating, regardless of how qualified the applicants in A2 are, so that it's impossible for anyone in A2 to get hired. That does appear to me to be rigged.

Comment: @cgb5436 "Qualified" is not enough in academic hiring. Most "qualified" people do not get jobs. If everyone in the department thinks people in A1 are better for the future of the department than people in A2, they should rank people in A2 low. That prevents hiring someone from A2 that may be qualified but not good for the future of the department. Yes, this sucks if you're in A2.

Comment: I don't think the people in A1 care about what's good for the future of the department; they just want everyone they hire to be in A1.

Comment: @cgb5436 this situation suggests a certain level of conflict or even dysfunction within the department, with factions that don’t get along sufficiently well to resolve their differences through discussion, so they resort to expressing their disagreements through a more overt power struggle. I’m not saying it’s a healthy situation - quite likely it isn’t. Nonetheless, I’m not seeing this sort of behavior as evidence that the people ranking candidates are corrupt or are abusing their power. So again, calling the search rigged seems misleading to me.

Comment: @cgb5436 by the way, in politics it’s common to see politicians making decisions that are bad for the country. Sometimes it’s because they are corrupt of course, but a lot of the times it’s just because they have bad ideas, and they genuinely believe their decisions are good for the country. The current situation can easily belong to this latter category.

Answer (score 4):

For any hiring, admissions, promotion, grants, or awards process where the decisions are made by humans using subjective criteria, there will be bias.  The particular bias will vary.

What any one individual tells you about the bias behind a particular process is not reliable.  It seems to me that such rumors are only a small step above conspiracy theories.

Looking at the list of people who have been hired an their prior records will tell you the truth.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say how "common" it is, having too little experience and no research. But I do know of places with large faculties where there was a definite balkanization. The factions really despised one another and students were wise to avoid the bickering and not to get involved.

And, factions can form for "reasons" other than research field.

It is, in a certain sense, unproductive, though the faculty was large enough that each faction was able to function independently. I don't actually know how if affected hiring, but I can see that it might have done.

Students just need to deal with it as it is, however. But, if it is not helpful overall, then the faculty, collectively, has means to deal with it. Some faculty, however, would rather just do the work and not get involved in faculty politics. To make a change you often have to "be that change".

---

And, if you were an A2 candidate that didn't get selected, you may be lucky overall.